# Patch Entity using lookups

Tags: entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api

I have the code below:

```
public class MyPatchController : EntitySetController<Books , int>
{ 
   protected override Books PatchEntity(int key, Delta<Books> patch)
        {
            var Book = db.books.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID== key);
            if (Book == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            patch.Patch(Book);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Book ;
        }
}
```

The Books entity has an AuthorID foreign key.  However, the client needs to do a PATCH using the author's name (not ID), and sends json as

```
{AuthorName : "Joe Smith"}
```

AuthorName is not in the model of Book.

What I am trying to do is use linq to look up the authorID, but Odata wont let me mix and match models when patching.

Is there a way I can make this work?

Note, I've tried using navigations in the models, but no avail

EDIT:
$metadata:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
  <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
    <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="Store.Models">
      <EntityType Name="BOOK">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="BOOK_ID"/>
        </Key>
        <Property Name="BOOK_ID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
        <Property Name="BOOK_NAME" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="AUTHOR_ID" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="AUTHOR">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="AUTHOR_ID"/>
        </Key>
        <Property Name="AUTHOR_ID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
        <Property Name="AUTHOR_NAME" Type="Edm.String"/>
      </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="Default">
      <EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
        <EntitySet Name="Author" EntityType="Store.Models.Author"/>
        <EntitySet Name="Book" EntityType="Store.Models.Book"/>
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: Could you share your $metadata? OData defines PATCH for only structural properties and looks like you are trying to patch the navigation property. I could suggest a different approach though if you share the $metadata.

Comment: Thanks Raghu, very simple schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the $metadata, It seems like there is no relationship between Books and Authors (I don't see any navigation properties in the model). So, the way to do this with OData is define an action "UpdateAuthor" on Book and then invoke it.

model builder code

```
var books = builder.EntitySet<Book>("books");
var updateAuthor = books.EntityType.Action("UpdateAuthor");
updateAuthor.Parameter<string>("name");
```

your controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateAuthor([FromODataUri]int key, ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    string name = (string)parameters["name"];

    // patch the author of book with id 'key'.
}
```

you would POST this json to `~/Author(42)/UpdateAuthor`.

```
{
    'name' : 'Joe Smith'
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Raghu, very helpful!